# List to text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a list of objects that holds groups of person. Each person has firstname, lastname, address and phone number.

I want to export that list into a text file looks like:

> groupA
>   Firstname-david
>   LastName-kantor
>   Addres-italy
>   PhoneNumber-123456

What should I do? So far I managed to export only the object type names:

```
public List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>();

string[] lines = elements.Select(phoneBookCore =>
    phoneBookCore.ToString()).ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: you want to use serialization here. you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)

Comment: @darko:add structre of PhoneBookCore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only the object type name because `PhoneBookCore.ToString()` gives you the object type name.

You have to specify how you want your file to look like. As MikeCorcoran a good way to do this is to use serialization. It is a very powerful way to store and retrieve data to/from file.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
foreach(var phoneBookCore in elements)
{
    lines.Add(phoneBookCore.GroupName);  // Adds the Group Name
    foreach(var person in phoneBookCore.Persons)
    {
        // Adds the information on the person
        lines.Add(String.Format("FirstName-{0}", person.FirstName));
        lines.Add(String.Format("LastName-{0}", person.LastName));
        lines.Add(String.Format("Address-{0}", person.Address));
        lines.Add(String.Format("PhoneNumber-{0}", person.PhoneNumber));
    }
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path,lines);
```